# Add nodes in a binary search tree

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

**Note: This is a home work assignment that I only want guidance to. Im not asking for any other help then that.**

I've looked up how to add nodes in a binary search tree in C# but I get very different types of answers. So, assuming that I have the node class:

```
class Node
{
    public int value;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;

    public Node(int v)
    {
        value = v;
        left = right = null;
    }
}
```

And the class where my add function is:

```
class BST
{
    public void addNode(int x, Node root)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(x);

        if (root == null)
        {
            root = newNode;
        }
        if (root.value == newNode.value)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (newNode.value < root.value)
        {
            if (root.left == null)
            {
                root.left = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                addNode(x, root.left);
            }
        }
        else if (newNode.value > root.value)
        {
            if (root.right == null)
            {
                root.right = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                addNode(x, root.right);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question now is: Im  pretty sure that I got the most of the logic right, but what im doubting is that when I call the function recursively, im not sure if the tree is acctually going to the left sub tree with that recursive call. Or have I done it right?

Comment: I think now is a good time to learn about [breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k80ex6de(v=vs.100).aspx), with these you can step through each line of code to make sure it is doing what you think it is doing. (Small note btw: If its not equal to and its not less than, then it *must* be greater than so you can just use `else` instead of `else if`)

Comment: You might get interested in Unit-Testing ([NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/), [VS-UnitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598957.aspx) for example). With this you can check if all constellations are treated appropriately. And in this case you know your code works.

Comment: I will look that up Sayse, and thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

If you think you have it right, you should test it to see.  Firstly, you should enhance your classes to make them easier to visualize in the debugger.  The obvious thing to do is to add a "ToString()" method to Node:

```
public class Node
{
    public int value;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;

    public Node(int v)
    {
        value = v;
        left = right = null;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, you can examine the values of your tree in Visual Studio simply by hovering your mouse over a class instance.  As per Sayse's suggestion, set a breakpoint in your code after you have begun to build the tree:

[image]

Hold your mouse over the root node.  A panel will appear with the "ToString()" value -- the node value, in fact, thanks to your "ToString()" override.  You will also see a "+" button.  If you click the button, Visual Studio will show you fields and properties of the class instance, and you can expand them recursively:

[image]

Having examined the values in the debugger, you may now want more sophisticated methods of extracting your data from your class, such as returning all the values in or under a `Node` in a list:

```
public class Node
{
    public IList<int> ToList()
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        AddToList(list);
        return list;
    }

    public void AddToList(List<int> list)
    {
        if (left != null)
            left.AddToList(list);
        list.Add(value);
        if (right != null)
            right.AddToList(list);
    }
}
```

That should allow you to see what you have and verify that it is what you expect.  You can use [`Enumerable.SequentialEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348567%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to add [asserts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your code to ensure the returned list is correct, like so:

```
    private static void TestBST()
    {
        var bst = new BST();
        Node root = new Node(23);
        bst.addNode(13, root);
        bst.addNode(-12, root);
        bst.addNode(1, root);
        Debug.Assert(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(root.ToList(), new int[] { -12, 1, 13, 23 }));
    }
```

You could also call the "ToList()" method from the [Immediate Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx), which allows you to type c# expressions while your program is stopped at a breakpoint and have them interpreted and the results shown interactively:

[image]

So, to sum up, whenever you are designing new classes, always be adding logic to make it easy to visualize, debug, and assert the correctness of your code.  The unit testing methodologies mentioned by TobiMcNamobi are formal ways to do this, but you can do it informally in homework code.

(By the way, you notice that I explicitly allocated a root node above, rather than using the BST class instance to create the root node?  Your remaining homework is to figure out why.)

Answer (score 0):

Your left/right logic is okay, for the most part, but the beginning is confusing:

```
if (root == null)
{
   root = newNode;
}
if (root.Value == newNode.Value) 
{
    return;
}
```

is actually to much. If `root` is `null` then something is wrong.
You may ignore that:

```
if (root == null) 
    return;    

if (newNode.Value < root.Value)
```

or let the user now, that something is wrong

```
if (root == null) 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("root");
```

but, if you want that `root` is changed outside of the `AddNode`call, you have to pass `root` as a [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx):

```
 public void AddNode(int x, ref Node root) 
 {
     Node newNode = new Node(x);
     this->AddNode(newNode, ref root);
 }

 private void AddNode(Node newNode, ref Node root)
 {
      if (root == null) 
      {
           root = newNode;
           return;
      }
      if (root.Value == newNode.Value) 
      {
           return;
      }
```

some things to improve:

It is good practice to write your method names in C# in UpperCamelCase, so you would call your method `AddNode`. This does not change the logic, but every programming language has its own style guide, that one should try to follow.
Same thing holds for public properties/fields, so call them `Left`, `Right` and `Value`.

every time you call `AddNode` you create a new Node object to hold your `x`.
That is overhead that can be avoided. Just create another funcktion `AddNode` that receives a Node as the first parameter and call that function from your function:

```
public void AddNode(int x, Node root) 
{
    Node newNode = new Node(x);
    this->AddNode(newNode, root);
}

private void AddNode(Node newNode, Node root)
{
    if (root == null) 
    {
        root = newNode;
    }
    if (root.Value == newNode.Value) 
    {
        return;
    } 
    else if (newNode.Value < root.Value) 
    {
        if (root.Left == null) 
        {
            root.Left = newNode;
        } 
        else 
        {
            AddNode(newNode, root.Left);
        }
    } 
    else if (newNode.Value > root.Value) 
    {
        if (root.Right == null) 
        {
            root.Right = newNode;
        } 
        else 
        {
            AddNode(newNode, root.Right);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. but the thing is that when root == null, that means that the tree dosent have a root value and im putting the new node as the root. can you not do that?

Comment: no, not like that, because setting `root = newNode` will only set `root` inside the method. i'll change the method signature, so it does what you want.